# Issue with Paypal BuyNow Button Variables

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have created sandbox.paypal PayNow button from below link

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/standard-integration

Then i tried to add various variables available for PayNow button. Some of them working are some of them are not working. I am listing down working and non working variables

Working Variables
1. return
2. cancel_return
3. no_note
4. item_name etc.

**Non Working Variables**
1. amount
2. no_shipping
3. cbt
4.cpp_logo_image etc

This way i am sending variables

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00" />
```

I got variables name from below paypal link

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

My code

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
        method="post" target="_top" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" /> <input
            type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXXXXXX" /> <input
            type="hidden" name="return"
            value="xxxxxxxx" /> <input
            type="hidden" name="cancel_return"
            value="xxxxxxxx" /> 


            <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="cpp_logo_image" value="http://science-all.com/images/wallpapers/background-image/background-image-10.jpg" />
            <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="userID" />
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
             <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="3.00" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="2.00" />

            <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Nexu Point Membership1">
            <input type="image"
            src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif"
            border="0" name="submit" alt="Please Wait..." /> <img alt=""
            border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"
            width="1" height="1" />
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you tried with hosted button or non hosted button?

Comment: @AnaheimElectronics I tried with hosted button and my form action URL=https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Comment: you should try with non hosted button. give it a try.

Comment: @AnaheimElectronics can we create non hosted button from sandbox?

Comment: You can AmitCharkha. Whenever you save your button in the button factory under your account, the button automatically a hosted button. You just can't simply add an extra variable to override it.

Comment: @AnaheimElectronics Paypal sample code also have hosted button id https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/

Comment: @AnaheimElectronics i had override variables in form <input> but they are not working.

Comment: If you read at the guide, they are not using a hosted button.

Comment: Can you post the code here? Alter your question. Put your code there.

Comment: @AnaheimElectronics i have posted code. Just now i tried with non hosted button it changes the amount but when i tried to do payment with my sanbox test account . Login failed. But same login authentication are working for my code which i have posted above in my question

Comment: AmitCharkha, you may only can override the value if using non hosted button.

Comment: @AnaheimElectronics You mean if i want to override variables then i have to use non hosted button? if Yes, then why some of variables are working and some are not working?